# Same Android project on other computer gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Yesterday I transferred project from my lap top on to desktop computer. On lap top everything works fine, on desktop it throws NullPointerException. I did nothing special, exported and imported project like I did many times.

LogCat:

[image]

Part of the code which throws exception(first line):

```
for (HashMap<String, String> data : items) {
    itemPreview.add(data);
}
```

Here is the entire class (logcat is attached):

```
public class Home extends Activity {
    TextView test;
    SearchLocation location;
    Button dialog;
    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    SearchLocation selectedLocation;
    HorizontalListView latestItemsList;
    HorizontalListView topStoresList;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    ImageLoader imgLoader;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> items;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> stores;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_logo);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.pickante_blue)));
        setTitle("");
        View location_setting = (View) findViewById(R.id.location_setting);
        latestItemsList = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.hlvItems);
        topStoresList = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.hlvTopStores);
        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

        /*********************************** CHANGE LOCATION POPUP WINDOW *************************************/
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.popup_change_location, null, false);

        // INSERT POPUP WINDOW EXAMPLE - LAYOUT INFLATER IS ABOWE SET
        // AUTOCOMPLETE TEXT EXAMPLE
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        final PopupWindow popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView,
                size.x - 50, size.y - 750, true);
        popWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.card_background));
        popWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.DialogAnimation);

        location_setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // popWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP, 0,350);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SelectLocation.class));

                // Fragment initialization
                /*
                 * Fragment fragment = new ChangeLoc(); FragmentTransaction ft =
                 * getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 * ft.add(R.id.frChangeLoc, fragment).commit();
                 */
            }
        });
        // END OF INSERT POPUP WINDOW EXAMPLE

        // RETRIVE LOCATION DATA FROM DB
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        location = db.getSingleLocation(1);
        String city = location.getValue();
        String loc_id = location.getKey();

        // SET LOCATION TEXT VIEW
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        test.setText(city);

        // RUN ASYNC TASK TO POPULATE LATEST ITEMS LISTVIEW
        LatestItems latestItems = new LatestItems();
        latestItems.execute(loc_id);

        TopStores topStores = new TopStores();
        topStores.execute(loc_id);
    }

    // Fetches latest items for home screen based on selected city
    private class LatestItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... loc_id) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Downloader object
            UrlDownloader downloader = new UrlDownloader();

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/web_services/home_screen_latest_items.php?loc_id="
                    + loc_id[0];

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service in background
                data = downloader.downloadUrl(url);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Downloader exception", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String downloadedData) {
            super.onPostExecute(downloadedData);

            //If web service returned data
            if (downloadedData != null) {
                JSONObject jObject;

                // Instantiate parser
                ItemJSONParser itemsParser = new ItemJSONParser();

                try {
                    // Put data into JSON Object and pass it to parser
                    jObject = new JSONObject(downloadedData);
                    items = itemsParser.parse(jObject);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
                }

                // Instantiate adapter. Provide Context, Item layout and
                // DataSource (result)
                ItemPreviewAdapter itemPreview = new ItemPreviewAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lvitem_homepage_item,
                        items);

                // Pass each data to from list into to adapter
                for (HashMap<String, String> data : items) {
                    itemPreview.add(data);
                }

                // Set adapter
                latestItemsList.setAdapter(itemPreview);
            }
        }
    }


    // Fetches latest items for home screen based on selected city
        private class TopStores extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... loc_id) {

                // For storing data from web service
                String data = "";

                // Downloader object
                UrlDownloader downloader = new UrlDownloader();

                // Building the url to the web service
                String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/web_services/home_screen_top_stores.php?loc_id="
                        + loc_id[0];

                try {
                    // Fetching the data from web service in background
                    data = downloader.downloadUrl(url);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Downloader exception", e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String downloadedData) {
                super.onPostExecute(downloadedData);

                //If web service returned data
                if (downloadedData != null) {
                    JSONObject jObject;

                    // Instantiate parser
                    StoreJSONParser storesParser = new StoreJSONParser();

                    try {
                        // Put data into JSON Object and pass it to parser
                        jObject = new JSONObject(downloadedData);
                        stores = storesParser.parse(jObject);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("ParserException", e.toString());
                    }

                    // Instantiate adapter. Provide Context, Item layout and
                    // DataSource (result)
                    TopStoresAdapter topStores = new TopStoresAdapter(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lvitem_homepage_topstore,
                            stores);

                    // Pass each data to from list into to adapter
                    for (HashMap<String, String> data : stores) {
                        topStores.add(data);
                    }

                    // Set adapter
                    topStoresList.setAdapter(topStores);
                }
            }

        }


    /*
     * FRAGMENT CLASS - Nema fragmenta ali se posle moze koristiti da se postavi
     * kroz fragmentManager
     */
    public static class ChangeLoc extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_change_location,
                    container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }

    // END OF FRAGMENT CLASS

    /****************************** SEARCH WIDGET INITIALIZATION ***********************************/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_action_bar, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        if (null != searchManager) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please  learn debugging.

Comment: why do you need the for loop. You already have `items` passed to the constructor of adapter class. If you have new items update items and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter to refersh listview

Comment: It has nothing to do with the computer you are working with. Show us the 185th line in LatestItems class

Comment: show us 185th line,I think error comes from JSONObject.

Comment: If the error is really in the line `for (HashMap<String, String> data : items) {` then `items` obviously is `null`. Using a try-catch to swallow any exception and then proceding as if nothing happened does not seem to be a good option.